# How can I search values of consecutive XML nodes with C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

I want to select nodes from an XML that have consecutive child nodes with values matching with the respective words from my search term.

Here is a sample XML:

```
<book name="Nature">
<page number="4">
    <line ln="10">
        <word wn="1">a</word>
        <word wn="2">white</word>
        <word wn="3">bobcat</word>
        <word wn="3">said</word>
    </line>
    <line ln="11">
        <word wn="1">Hi</word>
        <word wn="2">there,</word>
        <word wn="3">Bob.</word>
    </line>
</page>
```

My search term is **Hi Bob**. I want find all the  nodes from the above XML that contain two **consecutive** words with values **%Hi%** and **%Bob%**. Please note that I want to perform a partial and case-insensitive match for each word in my search term.

It should return the following output for the above XML:

```
ln="10" wn="2" wn="3"
```

Please note that line (ln=10) is selected because it contains two consecutive words (in the correct order) that match with the search term. white=%Hi% bobcat=%Bob%

However, the next line (ln=11) is not selected because the matching nodes are not consecutive.

Please note that all the words from the search term should be matched in order for it to be considered a match.

Thank you!

[Edit]
I tried the following solution and it yields the expected results. Is there a better or more efficient way of achieving this? The program has to search 100,000 XML files per day and each of them would be 300 KB to 50 MB.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\dummy.xml");
        var xLines = xDoc
                    .Descendants("page")
                    .Descendants("line");
        
        foreach (var xLine in xLines)
        {
            var xFirstWords = xLine
                                .Descendants("word")
                                .Where(item => item.Value.ToUpper().Contains("HI"));
            
            foreach (var xFirstWord in xFirstWords)
            {
                var xNextWord = xFirstWord.NodesAfterSelf().OfType<XElement>().First();
                if(xNextWord.Value.ToUpper().Contains("BOB"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(xLine.FirstAttribute.Value + " " + xFirstWord.FirstAttribute.Value + " " + xNextWord.FirstAttribute.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not my down vote but... This is not a free coding service. If you want assistance, you need to show a good faith effort to have attempted to solve the problem yourself. What have you tried? How do the results differ from what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much, Nicholas. It perfectly makes sense. I edited the question and added my code. It gives the expected results. However, I am not sure if it is the most efficient way. I have to search several thousands of XMLs and each of them runs in MBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could improvise my code. Please let me know if you have a better solution.

```
  XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\dummy.xml");
  var xLines = xDoc
              .Descendants("page")
              .Descendants("line");
  foreach (var xLine in xLines)
        {
            var xFirstWords = xLine
                                .Descendants("word")
                                .Where(item => item.Value.ToUpper().Contains("HI"))
                                .Where(item => item.ElementsAfterSelf("word").First().Value.ToUpper().Contains("BOB"));
                                

            foreach (var xFirstWord in xFirstWords)
            {
                var xNextWord = xFirstWord.ElementsAfterSelf("word").First();
                MessageBox.Show(xLine.FirstAttribute.Value + " " + xFirstWord.FirstAttribute.Value + " " + xNextWord.FirstAttribute.Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether the performance of this code will be better or worse, but I'm pretty sure it will be different, so it might be worth trying. Reconstitute the text of the line and then use a regular expression to match.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^.*Hi\s+\S+\s+Bob$*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\temp.xml");
foreach (XElement xLine in xDoc.Root.Descendants("line")) {
    string text = string.Join(" ", xLine.Elements("word").Select(x => x.Value));
    if (re.IsMatch(text)) {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things that come to mind performance-wise:

- `.Nodes` will be faster than `.Descendants`, as it only gets the direct children.
- Use `IndexOf` with `OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead of `ToUpper.Contains`.
- In the `foreach` instead of `NodesAfterSelf`, you can just hold the previous node.

```cs
var xLines = xDoc.Descendants("line");
        
foreach (var xLine in xLines)
{
    XNode prevWord = null;
    foreach (var word in xLine.Nodes("word"))
    {
        if(prevWord == null && word.Value.IndexOf("HI", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            prevWord == word;
        }
        else if(prevWord != null && word.Value.IndexOf("BOB"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xLine.FirstAttribute.Value + " " + prevWord.FirstAttribute.Value + " " + word.FirstAttribute.Value);
        }
    }
}
```